# Get the entered value on number input field, not the parsed

Tags: javascript, html, validation, input

I'm doing input validation on the following field and I want to set a default value. What I mean by default value is I want to set some value to input field if the field is empty.

```js
var inputBox = document.getElementById("inputBox");

inputBox.addEventListener("input", function() {
  validateInput(this);
});

inputBox.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  validateInput(this, e);
});

function validateInput(elm, e) {
  // handle keydown event
  if (e) {
    // do not allow floating-point numbers, if it's not expected
    if (!isFloat(elm.step)) {
      if (e.key == ".") {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    }
  }
  // handle input event
  else {
    // do not allow leading zeros
    while (elm.value.length > 1 && elm.value[0] === "0") {
      elm.value = elm.value.toString().slice(1);
    }
    // input should be between min and max
    if (elm.validity.rangeUnderflow) {
      elm.value = elm.min;
    } else if (elm.validity.rangeOverflow) {
      elm.value = elm.max;
    }
  }
}

function isFloat(x) {
  var f = parseFloat(x);
  var floor = Math.floor(f);
  var fraction = f - floor;
  if (fraction > 0) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="inputBox" min="0" max="16581375" step="1" value="0" />
```

In a very straightforward approach, I can add the following to the end of `validateInput()`

```
// set default value, empty field isn't allowed
if (elm.value == "") {
    elm.value = elm.min;
}
```

but this breaks some functionality. For example, I can't enter exponential values (e.g. `1e+5`).

Input field does its own check at input. The moment I enter `1e`, it evaluates to `NaN` and the `value` property of the element is set to `""`, but visually, `1e` is still entered on the field. So, you see, the entered value and the `HTMLInputElement.value` might differ.

To be able to set a default value, I should be able to check the entered value, not the parsed one by the element. Something like this would probably work:

```
// set default value, empty field isn't allowed
if (elm.value == "" && !elm.stringValue.includes(e)) {
    elm.value = elm.min;
}
```

But of course, there's no such `stringValue` property. One way I can think of to get around this problem is to use a text input field and do an extra validation for number.

Is there a way to make this work with number input field?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to parse exponential values into numbers.

I think, this solution should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18719988/6420563

This solution made for text field but i think it will also work for number input.

Comment: Input element with type set to number automatically validates the input using a regex. Makes sure it is a number. If it passes the validation, the input is stored in `value` property and parsed value is stored in `valueAsNumber` property. I can't check if the value is exponential or not at each input, because as soon as I type `1e`, it won't pass the validation, will evaluate to `NaN`, and `value` will be set to `""`. I can't get the actual entered value.

Comment: You must to validate value after conversion that described in example. After it you can overwrite value if it's needed.