# How to block user from adding + or - in input field in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, numbers

Basically, input field should accept only `1 - 999` values

Input Field :

```
<input
  type="number"
  value={value}
  onChange={this.props.onViltMaxUserChange}
  min="0"
  max="999"
/>
```

onChange :

```
  onViltMaxUserChange = _.throttle(e => {
    let { value, min, max } = e.target;
    if (value !== '' && !(_.inRange(value, min, max))) return false
    this.setState({ value: value });
  }, 50);
```

But User is able to add `---- or ++++`
onChange is not triggered when user inputs `+ or -`.
I Don't want to allow user to input these.

How can I do this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReactJs prevent e and dot in an input type number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45834885/reactjs-prevent-e-and-dot-in-an-input-type-number)

Comment: add this event : - onKeyDown={(evt) => ["e", "E", "+", "-"].includes(evt.key) && evt.preventDefault()}

Answer (score 0):

You could validate your input value with regular expression
`/^[0-9]{1,3}$/.test(value)` in `onKeyUp` event.