# How do I restrict the input to only number at the input box?

Tags: html, reactjs, react-bootstrap

```
   <Form.Group>
              <Form.Control. onChange={e => { console.log('e------',e.target.value)}}
             type='number' />
   </Form.Group>
```

I set the type on can be number, but when I click "enter"(return button) and "-",

I still can see "e" and "-" at my input box, but I only want user see number at the inputbox.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReactJs prevent e and dot in an input type number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45834885/reactjs-prevent-e-and-dot-in-an-input-type-number)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this

```
<Form.Control type="number" onKeyDown={ (evt) => evt.key === 'e' && evt.preventDefault() } />
```

As per an existing answer to a similar question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54561804/7344164)

Answer (score 0):

You can try regex.

```
  <Form.Group>
       <Form.Control. 
          onChange={e =>  if(e.target.value.match("/^\d*(\.\d+)?$/")){
              console.log('e------',e.target.value)
          }}
       />
   </Form.Group>
```