# toFixed function on large numbers

Tags: javascript

I have following number with e+ on it

```
9.074701047887939e+304
```

I want to take only 9.07

So I tried below , but its not working , its returning full output

```js
console.log(parseFloat(9.074701047887939e+304).toFixed(2));
```

Ps : I also need the code to work for normal numbers aswell for example 892.0747010 , should output 892.07

Comment: do you mean you want `9.07e+304` or `9.07` ?

Comment: I just need 9.07

Comment: so for `9.1` and `9.1e+304`, what do you want as the result?

Comment: console.log((parseFloat(9.074701047887939e+304).toPrecision(3)).substr(0,4));

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18719775/parsing-and-converting-exponential-values-to-decimal-in-javascript

Comment: it also depends on what you want for `9.074701047887939e-304` as well. Please see updated answer, including negative numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned for both `9.074701047887939e+304` and `9.074701047887939`,  you want the answer to be `9.07`.

For `9.074701047887939e-304` I assume you want `9.07` too, although you might actually want `0.00`.

```js
const twoDecimal = (a =>
  (a.toString().match(/e/) ? Number(a.toString().match(/[^e]*/)[0]) : a).toFixed(2)
);

console.log(twoDecimal(9.074701047887939e+304));
console.log(twoDecimal(9.074701047887939e-304));
console.log(twoDecimal(9.074701047887939));
console.log(twoDecimal(789.074701047887939));
console.log(twoDecimal(0.00001));
console.log(twoDecimal(0.20001));

console.log(twoDecimal(-9.074701047887939e+304));
console.log(twoDecimal(-9.074701047887939e-304));
console.log(twoDecimal(-9.074701047887939));
console.log(twoDecimal(-789.074701047887939));
console.log(twoDecimal(-0.00001));
console.log(twoDecimal(-0.20001));

console.log(twoDecimal(0));
```

Comment: Its adding e+1 for all numbers

Comment: `.toPrecision() ` added

Comment: we have different behaviors... his cannot process negative number currently... and his would give `"0.00"` for `-9.074701047887939e-304`.  You can try http://jsben.ch/FtNBK for benchmark

Answer (score 3):

`toFixed` trims digits after the *decimal point*, but your actual number is very large - it doesn't have a decimal point.

If you don't know in advance whether the number is large or not, one option is to call `toFixed(2)` on the number first (trimming off and properly rounding digits past the decimal point for small numbers), then using a regular expression to take the numeric part only (removing the `e` if it exists), then call `toFixed(2)` again (trimming off and properly rounding digits past the decimal point for large numbers):

```js
const fix = num => Number(
  num.toFixed(2).match(/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/)[0]
).toFixed(2);

console.log(fix(9.074701047887939e+304));
console.log(fix(123.4567));
console.log(fix(12345));
```

Comment: You can adjust the solution, maybe implement it as "remove everything from two digits after the decimal onwards", and use `(bignumber).toString().replace(/(\.\d\d).*/,"$1")`

Comment: Which is faster , yours or nopole answer ?