# Extract double number value with exponent from text

Tags: c#, regex, string-parsing

How could I extract a number of type double which may have exponent from a string with more character?

For example extract `56.8671311035e-06` from

> "this is a string with a number inside 56.8671311035e-06 and the string continues here"

I guess it could be done using regular expressions, but my knowledge of them is very limited.

Comment: **Possible duplicate:** [Parsing scientific notation sensibly?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/638565/1497596)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yep, I'd say regular expressions are your friend here:

```
var match = Regex.Match(input, @"[0-9.]+e[-+][0-9]+");
```

Or you can prevent matching multiple decimal points with the following (the last one will be treated as the "proper" one):

```
@"\b[0-9]+(.[0-9]+)e[-+][0-9]+\b"
```

**Edit:** Here's a more complete one that will allow optional exponents and will also allow for the decimal point to be at the *start* of the number:

```
@"[\d]*\.?[\d]+(e[-+][\d]+)?"
```

Comment: `e-` should be `e[-+]?`

Comment: Indeed, `e[-+][0-9]+` should be `(e[-+][0-9]+)?` as the Q said "may have exponent".

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
string test = "this is a string with a number inside 56.8671311035e-06 and the string continues here";
string expoNum = Regex.Match(test,@"[\d.]+e[-+]?\d+").Value;
```

Comment: `e-` should be `e[-+]?`

Comment: To match 56.8671311035e-06 or 56.8671311035e+06 or 56.8671311035e06

Comment: @ClickRick, thanks done. I don't have the knowledge of how they can be

Comment: Indeed, `e[-+][0-9]+` should be `(e[-+][0-9]+)?` as the question said "may have exponent".

Comment: @ClickRick, who is Q?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51935/discussion-between-amit-joki-and-clickrick)