# Invalidate scientific notation with 0 value exponent or trailing 0s

Tags: regex, zero, scientific-notation

I am using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/658662/1382306) to regex scientific notation:

```
/-?(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?/
```

I'd like to add a slight amount of space conservation, so I'd like to also forbid trailing zeros after the decimal point and zero value as the exponent.

I think that adding `[1-9]` after `\.\d` will enforce no trailing zeros, but I think it will also force at least two numbers after `.` which is undesirable.

I do not possess the necessary experience to modify this regex properly.

How can my intent be implemented?

Comment: Gracchus, if you haven't tried regex hero, you may want to give it a shot.  It allows one to experiment with regex statements and test them with various data to no end. [RegexHero.net](http://regexhero.net).

Comment: @Gracchus: http://regex101.com/ might help, then (works online, requires no installation)

Comment: @Gracchus: If you're looking for an interactive tutorial, try http://regexone.com For a good reference, use this site: http://regular-expressions.info For a book, try Mastering Regular Expressions by Jeffrey Friedl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make this simple change:

```
/-?(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:\.\d*[1-9])?(?:[eE][+-]?[1-9]\d*)?/
```

Note that `[1-9]\d*` will forbid exponants with a leading zero.

Comment: @Gracchus: Yes but since exponants with leading zero are excluded, 0 valued exponents are excluded too.

Comment: @Gracchus: However, if you need a tolerance about leading zeros, you can use :`[eE][+-]?0*[1-9]\d*`

Answer (score 1):

> I think that adding `[1-9]` after `\.\d` will enforce no trailing zeros, but I think it will also force at least two numbers after `.`

No `\d` is actually `\d*`, which means that it will only enforce one `[1-9]` (preceded by **none or many** `\d`s). So

```
/-?(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:\.\d*[1-9])?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?/
/-?(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:\.\d*[1-9])?(?:[eE][+\-]?[1-9]\d*)?/ # no (leading) zero exponent
```

*will* work. It does however enforce one digit after the dot, if a decimal part is apparent.