# How to convert CSS transform matrix back to its component properties

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transforms

I have obtained a CSS transform matrix of an element by using `getComputedStyle()` method as follows.

```
var style = window.getComputedStyle(elem1, null);
var trans = style.transform;
```

> trans = matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 1320, 290)

Is there a way to back calculate the transform matrix to get the original CSS rules ie. the values to translate , rotate, skew properties. I'm assuming it can be calculated by reversing the method used to form the matrix.
P.S. - The values of transform properties are given in percentages, I want to back calculate these percentage values from the matrix.

CSS transform - `transform: translate(200%, 500%);`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to do that!

The parameters to matrix come in this order:
`matrix(scaleX(),skewY(),skewX(),scaleY(),translateX(),translateY())`

Read more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp)

If you want to retrieve the numbers from that string (matrix(1,0,0,1,720,290) you could use this regex:

```
style = window.getComputedStyle(elem1, null);
trans = style.transform;
numberPattern = /-?\d+\.?\d*/g;

values = trans.match( numberPattern );
```

This will return the following array:

```
["1", "0", "0", "1", "720", "290"]
```

## Edit after comments

The values returned in the window.getComputedStyle are the computed values (i.e. the percentages you used are being parsed to pixel values). You can reverse that calculation, but you need to know what the percentage is using to figure out how many pixels it should be.

> ### Enter CSS3 Transforms
>
> One interesting thing about CSS transforms is that, when applying them with percentage values, they base that value on the dimensions of the element which they are being implemented on, as opposed to properties like top, right, bottom, left, margin, and padding, which only use the parent's dimensions (or in case of absolute positioning, which uses its closest relative parent).
>   *[Source](https://davidwalsh.name/css-vertical-center)*

if you use the following calculation, you should be able to get the percentages you used:

```
style = window.getComputedStyle(elem1, null);
trans = style.transform;
numberPattern = /-?\d+\.?\d+|\d+/g;

values = trans.match( numberPattern );

computedTranslateX = values[4];
computedTranslatey = values[5];

xPercentage = (computedTranslateX / elem1.offsetWidth) * 100;
yPercentage = (computedTranslateY / elem1.offsetHeight) * 100;
```

Comment: I dont want the values in the matrix . I want the values that i gave in CSS as translate, rotate and skew properties.

Comment: Could you post your CSS so I can see what values you are expecting to get back?

Comment: For catching negative values, consider to use pattern: `/-?\d+/g;`

Comment: This works great, however I ran into an edge-case; Safari often returns values with exponents ie `-2.544326192711535e-16`. The `numberPattern` regexp will split this into two matches like `[2.544326192711535, 16]`

Comment: @Benjamin You're totally right. I looked up what I could do to make it work, but I seem to need some more testing before I can update my answer. If you want to have some code that you could use, check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638565/parsing-scientific-notation-sensibly) for some help guidance.

Comment: @DouwedeHaan Thanks. For a quick fix I am using `style.transform.split(/matrix\(|,|\)/).filter(v => v !== '')`