# Regex for splitting numbers and numbers followed by a certain string?

Tags: python, regex

I am new to the regex world. I am trying to make a regex that is able to delimit a number from a number that is followed by a certain string.

Example:

```
input: '1002 900 600 700 800 234 Andrew'
output: single_numbers: 1002, 900, 600, 700, 800
        special_number: 234

input: '55 89Andrew 78 622 11 22 33 44 55' 
output: single_numbers: 55 78 622 11 22 33 44 55
        special_number: 89
```

I found this regex that is able to extract the numbers : `"[-+]?[.]?[\d]+(?:,\d\d\d)*[\.]?\d*(?:[eE][-+]?\d+)?"`, but it gives all available numbers:
Example:

```
s = '89Andrew 78 622'
re.findall("[-+]?[.]?[\d]+(?:,\d\d\d)*[\.]?\d*(?:[eE][-+]?\d+)?", s)

output: ['89', '78', '622']
```

How to make it work?

Thanks !!!

Comment: `<num_regex>(?=\s*WORD\b)` and `<num_regex>\b(?!\s*WORD\b)`? See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/sFpO6f).

Comment: num_regex is "[-+]?[.]?[\d]+(?:,\d\d\d)*[\.]?\d*(?:[eE][-+]?\d+)?" ? @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Yes! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two regexps to get these different values:

```
rf'{num_rx}(?=\s*Andrew\b)'
rf'{num_rx}\b(?!\s*Andrew\b)'
```

Here, `(?=\s*Andrew\b)` is a positive lookahead that requires zero or more whitespace and then a whole word `Andrew` (`\b` is a word boundary), and `\b(?!\s*Andrew\b)` makes sure there is a word boundary matched first (after a number) and then it fails the match if there is zero or more whitespace and then a whole word `Andrew` immediately to the right of that location.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/sFpO6f):

```py
import re
s = '89Andrew 78 622'
num_rx = r'[-+]?\.?\d+(?:,\d{3})*\.?\d*(?:[eE][-+]?\d+)?'
special_match = re.search(rf'{num_rx}(?=\s*Andrew\b)', s)
if special_match:
    print( special_match.group() )
print(re.findall(rf'{num_rx}\b(?!\s*Andrew\b)', s))
```

Output:

```
89
['78', '622']
```

**NOTE**: I did not modify your number matching regex, but you might want to see other existing options at [Parsing scientific notation sensibly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638565/parsing-scientific-notation-sensibly).