# How to check if a String with integers matches a specific pattern in Java?

Tags: java, regex

I only want Strings with a very specific format to be allowed in my methods.
The format is "Intx^Int". Here are some concrete examples:

- "5x^2"
- "-21x^5"
- "14x^-12"

I tried the following code, but it doesn't seem to work correctly:

```java
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\dx^\\d");
System.out.println(p.matcher("14x^-12").matches());
```

Comment: Because you only match a single digit without any sign in front and do not escape `^`. `"-?\\d+x\\^-?\\d+"` can work for you.

Comment: That worked! If you throw that in an answer and quickly explain the -? syntax (I'm unfamiliar), I'll give you the checkmark!

Comment: Another approach: split the string on "x^" and verify that you get two substrings and that you can convert each of them to an integer. If everything goes fine, then the original string was valid.

Comment: `-?` means that a literal `-` character can be there, but it doesn't have to be (`?` means it's optional).  Wiktor has added it so that your negative numbers still match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only match a single digit (not whole numbers) without any sign in front (it seems you want to match optional `-` chars in front of the numbers). You also failed to escape the `^` char that is a special regex metacharacter denoting the start of a string (or line if `Pattern.MULTILINE` option is used).

You can use

```java
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+x\\^-?\\d+");
System.out.println(p.matcher("14x^-12").matches());
```

The pattern matches

- `-?` - an optional `-`
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `x` - an `x`
  -`\^` - a `^` char
- `-?` - an optional `-`
- `\d+` - one or more digits

To support numbers with fractions, you might further tweak the regex:

```java
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?x\\^-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?");
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-?\\d*\\.?\\d+x\\^-?\\d*\\.?\\d+");
```

Also, see [Parsing scientific notation sensibly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/638565/3832970).